# DV1 Visa entry to USA

Tags: usa, visa, greencard

Can I enter USA with DV1 visa? I live in Macedonia and I have the DV1 visa but I am not sure if I can enter USA or not?

Comment: Do you mean because of a COVID-19 restriction or...?

Answer (score 1):

Proclamation 10014, which previously banned immigrants from entering the US, was revoked by [Proclamation 10149](https://www.federalregister.gov/documents/2021/03/01/2021-04279/revoking-proclamation-10014) on February 24, 2021. If your immigrant visa is still valid, you can use it to enter the US any time before it expires.

Previous answer:

<s>Assuming that the immigrant visa was issued after April 23, 2020, you are banned from entering the US with it by [Proclamation 10014](https://www.federalregister.gov/d/2020-09068), which has been extended to March 31, 2021 by [Proclamation 10131](https://www.federalregister.gov/d/2021-00039). So you cannot enter the US until then (or until the ban is revoked by President Biden if he revokes it before then).</s>

Comment: Immigrant visas issued before April 2020 have all expired, haven't they?

Comment: @phoog: I think so

Comment: Biden revoked a bunch of immigration restrictions on April 20th.  Was this among them?

Comment: @phoog: You mean January 20? No, this has not been revoked.

Comment: Yes, I meant January 20th.

Comment: @phoog: It has been revoked. I have updated the answer.